# письмо не доходит до получателя

Tags: php, email

У меня на сайте есть регистрация. Сегодня решил в целях безопасности добавить регистрацию через почту (чтобы при нажатии на ссылку в письме подтверждалась регистрация).

Решил сперва протестировать без всего лишнего:

```
<?php
    $to = 'reijiakkerman@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'hello';
    $message = 'HELLO';
    $headers = 'From: reijiakkerman@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $a = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $a . "\n";
```

Таким образом я попытался отправить сообщение себе, я проверял работу отправки сообщения себе через телефон и письмо пришло.

Вопрос: `mail()` возвращает `true` - т.е. письмо отправляется, но почему письмо до меня так и не доходит?

Comment: true не означает что письмо отправляется, это означает что оно было [успешно принято к отправлению.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov с этим я ознакомился еще перед написанием этого кода, прочитайте вопрос внимательнее - он не в том что не отправляется, а в том что не доходит. Может я чего то не делаю для успешного сопровождения этого письма? Что то же должно контроллировать доставку письма? Если да то что за сервисы за это отвечают? Как я понял из беглого гуглежа за отправку писем отвечает уже вовсе не HTTP протокол а SMTP. Но вот тут и проблема - если в роли HTTP сервера может выступать Apache - то что реализует работу SMTP протокола?

Comment: ох.... mail отправляет по умолчанию письма через программу sendmail. А не через HTTP-сервер. Он вообще этим не занимается. Я бы сказал, что еще sendmail надо бы настраивать. Но в современных реалиях почту, отправляемую с произвольного хоста, в принципе не  будет принимать никто. Для этого нужен полноценный публичный почтовый-сервер (публичный белый IP, корректно настроенные записи в DNS, сам почтовый сервер(ПО), SSL-сертификаты, настройка подписей, прогрев и попадание в белые списки и т.д. и т.п.)